# Show a Users username in Devise Login Alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to change the message that’s displayed when a user logs in via devise. In my User model i have a column :name, i want to display that within the message, so in my devise.en.yml file I can change text, I've tried calling the users name from the model like so

```
signed_in: 'Hello %{User.name}, Time to get cooking'
```

though is is showing the message as a string like so

```
Hello %{User.name}, Time to get cooking
```

How do i pull the name from the model? This is probably very simple so please excuse my naivety

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ok so after a little bit of googling/stackoverflow i have the answer

Create the following folder in Controllers

```
app/controllers/my_devise
```

Create the controller Sessions within my_devise (Sessions controller is what devise uses to manage the user_sign_in and sign_out process

You need to inherit the devise sessions controller within your newly created sessions controller

```
class MyDevise::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
```

You can copy the devise sessions controller here

I amended the create action like so

```
set_flash_message :notice, :signed_in, :name => resource.name if is_navigational_format?
```

notice i use name and not User.name, it seems as if devise already knows this is the User model, which makes sense

Within my routes i added

```
 devise_for :users,
          :controllers => {
          :sessions => 'my_devise/sessions'
          }
```

Within my devise.en.yml file i added

```
signed_in: 'Hello %{name}, Time to get cooking'
```

again using name not user.name

Answer (score 1):

You should really call `rails g migration AddUsernameToUser`
Then run `rake db:migrate`

Then devise has a built in function which is, `<%= current_user.username %>`

Hope that helps!